# Beamer: Overlay with `pgfplots` that read data from a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, overlays

I want to show a chart by the package `pgfplots` only on a subsequent slide of a frame. However using `\uncover` or `\visible` on the chart generates an error: `Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" {Other Categories} 0 0 . }` with the MWE below.

If I remove the `\uncover`, the file compiles and produces a static frame as I show below.

**How can I display the chart only on certain slides?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \uncover<2->{
        \begin{figure}
            \caption{A Stacked Bar Chart}
            \smallskip
            {\centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
                    \begin{axis}[
                    ybar stacked,
                    xlabel={Category},
                    ylabel={Quantity},
                    ymin=0,
                    symbolic x coords={A,B/C,D,Other Categories},
                    xtick=data,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.5,-0.3)},
                        anchor=north,
                    },
                    axis lines=left,
                    enlarge x limits=true,
                    enlarge y limits={true,upper},
                    ]
                    \addplot[fill=white] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories} 24.4417   18.9708   28.7252   28.7150
                        A                  27.1738    2.9262   28.9467   14.5613
                        B/C                 3.8096    8.3549    4.7284   24.0084
                        D                  27.4013   16.4064   29.1178    4.2566
                    };
                    \addplot[fill=red] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories}      0         0       .           .
                        A                  8.4352   19.1898       .           .
                        B/C               18.3147   13.1148       .           .
                        D                 15.8441    0.7142       .           .
                    };
                    \legend{White part, Red part}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \par}
        \end{figure}
    }   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Static frame:
[image: Static Frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `pgfplots` runs a survey phase that clashes with the way `beamer` builds up the frames. The good news is that there is a Ti*k*Z library for these purposes, `overlay-beamer-styles`, which allow you to achieve what I think you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Variant A: picture completely invisible on frame 1}    
        \begin{figure}
            \uncover<2->{\caption{A Stacked Bar Chart}}
            \smallskip
            {\centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,visible on=<2>]
                    \begin{axis}[
                    ybar stacked,
                    xlabel={Category},
                    ylabel={Quantity},
                    ymin=0,
                    symbolic x coords={A,B/C,D,Other Categories},
                    xtick=data,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.5,-0.3)},
                        anchor=north,
                    },
                    axis lines=left,
                    enlarge x limits=true,
                    enlarge y limits={true,upper},
                    ]
                    \addplot[fill=white] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories} 24.4417   18.9708   28.7252   28.7150
                        A                  27.1738    2.9262   28.9467   14.5613
                        B/C                 3.8096    8.3549    4.7284   24.0084
                        D                  27.4013   16.4064   29.1178    4.2566
                    };
                    \addplot[fill=red] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories}      0         0       .           .
                        A                  8.4352   19.1898       .           .
                        B/C               18.3147   13.1148       .           .
                        D                 15.8441    0.7142       .           .
                    };
                    \legend{White part, Red part}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}}
            \par
        \end{figure}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Variant B: picture transparent on frame 1}   
        \begin{figure}
            \uncover<2->{\caption{A Stacked Bar Chart}}
            \smallskip
            {\centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,alt=<1>{opacity=0.1}]
                    \begin{axis}[
                    ybar stacked,
                    xlabel={Category},
                    ylabel={Quantity},
                    ymin=0,
                    symbolic x coords={A,B/C,D,Other Categories},
                    xtick=data,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.5,-0.3)},
                        anchor=north,
                    },
                    axis lines=left,
                    enlarge x limits=true,
                    enlarge y limits={true,upper},
                    ]
                    \addplot[fill=white] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories} 24.4417   18.9708   28.7252   28.7150
                        A                  27.1738    2.9262   28.9467   14.5613
                        B/C                 3.8096    8.3549    4.7284   24.0084
                        D                  27.4013   16.4064   29.1178    4.2566
                    };
                    \addplot[fill=red] table [header=false,x index = {0}, y index = {1}] {
                        {Other Categories}      0         0       .           .
                        A                  8.4352   19.1898       .           .
                        B/C               18.3147   13.1148       .           .
                        D                 15.8441    0.7142       .           .
                    };
                    \legend{White part, Red part}
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}}
            \par
        \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]